# Adding a space at the end of each element in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, whitespace, string-concatenation

Assuming a data frame like this:

```
Names <- data.frame(Companies=c('NINTENDO', 'SONY', 'MICROSOFT'))
```

I want to make R gives each element (NINTENDO, SONY, AND MICROSOFT) a space at the end of their names, so that the final output is exactly like the one above, but just with an added space at the end of each name:

```
Names <- data.frame(Companies=c('NINTENDO ', 'SONY ', 'MICROSOFT '))
```

Aa an extra question, is there a similar way to add a space in front each names too? Like such:

```
Names <- data.frame(Companies=c(' NINTENDO', ' SONY', ' MICROSOFT'))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using `sub`.

```
sub("$", " ", Names$Companies)
[1] "NINTENDO "  "SONY "      "MICROSOFT "
sub("^", " ", Names$Companies)
[1] " NINTENDO"  " SONY"      " MICROSOFT"
```

In regular expressions, `$` indicates the end of the string. `^` indicates the beginning.

Comment: Thank you! If I were to combine the two, would this work?

    Companies_1_20 <- sub("$^", " ", Companies_1_20$Companies_Generated)

Answer (score 2):

Or a straight forward approach would be using `paste` or `paste0`

```
paste(" ",Names$Companies)
#[1] " NINTENDO"  " SONY"      " MICROSOFT"

paste(Names$Companies, " ")
#[1] "NINTENDO "  "SONY "      "MICROSOFT "
```

You can also combine them by

```
paste(" ",Names$Companies, " ")
#[1] "  NINTENDO  "  "  SONY  "      "  MICROSOFT  "
```

As @Karolis commented `paste` would add a default space as `sep`erator use `paste0` instead

```
paste0(" ",Names$Companies, " ")
#[1] " NINTENDO "  " SONY "      " MICROSOFT "
```

Comment: This example adds 2 spaces to each side, not one. Since `paste` is also joining using a space " " as a separator. `paste0` can be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `sprintf`:

```
sprintf(" %s ", Names$Companies)
# [1] " NINTENDO "  " SONY "      " MICROSOFT "
```